# $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is irrational, $f(p/q)=q$ if $p/q$ is an irreducible fraction

Tags: real-analysis

Give $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is irrational, $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=q$ if $\displaystyle \frac{p}{q}$ is a irreductible fraction with $p>0$, $f(0)=0$. Show that $f$ is not bounded at any interval nondegenerate.

Comment: Looked bounded to me. On $[a,b]$, $\min(a,-1)\leq f(x)\leq \max(b,1)$.

Comment: Are you sure that $f(\frac pq) = \frac1q$ and not $f(\frac pq) = q$ or $f(\frac pq) = p$? Your function is bounded.

Comment: [This function is continuous at irrational points](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960887/show-that-the-function-f-is-continuous-only-at-the-irrational-points/960903#960903), thus locally bounded around them

Comment: sorry, is $f(p/q)=q$

Comment: show that every interval contains a rational number of arbitrarily large denominator.

Comment: I show that exists for every interval $(a,b)$ an irrational $m/q$, arguing that $\exists q_1 \in \mathbb{N}, b-a>1/q_1>0$ and given arbitrarily $A>0$, $\exists q_2 \in \mathbb{N}, q_2>A$, then, $q=max\{q_1,q_2\}, \exists m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a<m/q<b$ and $f(m/q)=q>A$, but my problem is, happens if $m$ divides $q$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I=(a,b)$, with $a<b$, and $q$ be a prime number, such that
$$
q>\frac{1}{b-a}.
$$ 
Such $q$ exists, as the primes are infinitely many.

Then, 
$$
a=\frac{aq}{q}<\frac{\lfloor aq\rfloor+1}{q}\le \frac{aq+1}{q}=a+\frac{1}{q}<a+(b-a)=b,
$$
and hence $\displaystyle \frac{\lfloor aq\rfloor+1}{q}\in(a,b) $ and clearly
$$
f\left(\frac{\lfloor aq\rfloor+1}{q}\right)=q.
$$
Thus in every interval $f$ takes arbitrarily large values.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Pick some interval $[a,b]$ and some integer $n$.

Prove that for each $1 \leq k \leq n$ there are finitely many fractions with denominator $k$ in the interval. As there are infinitely many rational numbers, there must be one with denominator larger than $n$.