# Utility of codomain

Tags: functions

Let $f(x): [-1, 1] \rightarrow R$ with $f(x) = \sin^{-1} x$.

So it's mapping from domain $[-1, 1]$ to codomain $R$. And we know it's range is $[-π/2, π/2]$.

But what's the utility of defining the codomain? Why not simply write the function as:

$f(x): [-1, 1] \rightarrow [-π/2, π/2]$

---

Edit: This question is a duplicate of [Significance of codomain of a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3757779/739167) and might be closed.

Comment: $f(x)$ is a number. It is not the proper notation for a function.

Comment: You use the codomain before you know what the range is. As far as I know, there is no specific term to denote the *starting set* of a function before you know what the domain is.

Comment: @Christoph Yes! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f: [-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ with $f(x) = \sin^{-1} x$

and

$g: [-1,1] \to \mathbb [-π/2, π/2]$ with $g(x) = \sin^{-1} x$.

Then $f$ and $g$ are different functions ! For example $g$ is surjective, but $f$ is not surjective.