# Is there a function such that when we change its values on $\mathbb{Q}$ its set of discontinuities is exactly $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: analysis

Given a continuous function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
when we change its value at a finite set $D$ of points, we
get a function whose set of discontinuities is exactly $D$. However this is not true in general when $D$ is infinite. For example when
$D=\mathbb{Q}$, is there a continuous function
$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that there exists another function
$\tilde{f}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that differs from
$f$ exactly at points in $\mathbb{Q}$, such that the set of
discontinuities of $\tilde{f}$ is exactly $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: There certainly is! Let $f$ be identically zero, and $\tilde{f}$ be the function defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/960887/1508).

Comment: @TonyK You're right! Thanks!