# What is the cardinality of the number of jumps in a Lévy process on a given time interval?

Tags: limits, continuity, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

If a Lévy process can be defined as a right continuous process with existing left limits, then according to the following linked theorem ([Prove that the number of jump discontinuities is countable for any function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263606/prove-that-the-number-of-jump-discontinuities-is-countable-for-any-function?fbclid=IwAR1cnzoRk8QBu0qX8pEjQjSarVhaU5D8zIKozf7sV4lG1f77rk1i7Cc9t2U)) I would say an arbitrary trajectory of a Lévy process can have countable many jumps on a given interval (or compact time set).

Even though, there are Lévy processes that jumps continuum infinitely many times on a given time interval, e.g.: Cauchy process...

As I understand, the Cauchy process jumps in every $t$, since its Lévy triplet is $(0,0,\nu)$, where $\nu (dx)=dx/(\pi x^2)$ according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_process. So there is no continuous part in a Cauchy process, which means it jumps in almost every $t$. Is it even possible for a Lévy process to jump continuum infinitely many times?

It seems a contradiction to me. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: The Cauchy process does only jump a countable number of times and I hope you haven't read the contrary somewhere... Having no continuous part only means that there is no continuous motion. Take the following much easier example of a Lévy process with characteristics $(0,0,\nu)$ with a finite measure $\nu$. Then it has no continuous part, but a.s. only a finite(!) number of jumps! Now, the Cauchy process is more complicated. And the important part is that the set of jumps times is dense(!!) in $[0,+\infty)$, but not uncountable.

Comment: But doesn't it mean the Cauchy process has piecewise constant parts so there is a positive probability, that a given "increment" is zero?...but if the Cauchy process has Cauchy distributed increments/jumps, then taking zero should have zero probability...or because the set of jumps is dense it is not true that the process has piecewise constant parts?...Anyway, you are right about noting that the first Lévy parameter equal to zero and the second parameter sigma=0 just means that there is no trend and diffusion part, but it doesn't claim that there is no continuous part, e.g.: Poisson process

Comment: @MushuNrek, if you wrote down your previous comment as an answer I would mark it as a good answer...it already helped me a lot...

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean with the zero increment. If you detail your thoughts, I might be able to give some insights. If you want to have a look at some very weird behaviour that can happen when you have a countable number of jumps, you might want to look up the Cantor function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function). It is not exactly the same thing, as the Cantor function is continuous (so that it doesn't have jumps!).
I think it is only suited to write this down as an answer, when everything is cleared up :)

Comment: Ok...So where do I go wrong with the following train of thoughts? Cauchy process is a pure jump process and the number of jumps are countable (as you write above). I think it implies the following: with positive probability, there are $t$ points, where $X_{t+h}-X_{t}=0$ (other words: $\mathbf{P}\left(X_{t+h}-X_{t}=0\right)>\varepsilon)$. But it sounds like contradiction, since $X_{t+h}-X_{t}$ are Cauchy distributed variables (with zero parameter), and we know that the Cauchy distribution is a continuous distribution, therefore $\mathbf{P}\left(X_{t+h}-X_{t}=0\right)=0$.

Comment: It does indeed imply the opposite: for every $t$ and every $h$, $X_{t+h}\neq X_t$ a.s. Imagine for simplicity that the set of jumps is exactly $\mathbb{Q}$. (This is not the case, but the set of jumps behaves in exactly the same way as it is countable and dense!) Then, for any $t$ and any $h$, there is always some $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $q\in (t,t+h)$ [because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense!]. That means that there will always be a jumps between any two points of time and therefore, the process isn't constant on any time interval.

Comment: Agree, but still don't understand 100%... when you write we can always find a $q$ between $\left(t,t+h\right)$, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense, doesn't it mean it jumps in every $t$? You say a $q_{1}\in\left(t,t+h\right)$, where $X$ jumps, but then I can always say a $q_{2}\in\left(t,t+q_{1}\right)$ where $X$ also has jump (i.e. a “closer jump point to $t$”), but we can play this game forever, so I would say it means $X$ is not continuous in $t$, i.e. $X$ jumps in $t$. But the same reasoning hold for every $t$, so the cardinalty of jumps why is not continuum?

Comment: I think it is a very similar "problem" to the case of Dirichlet function...

Comment: I agree that this is extremely difficult to visualise and I am not sure that I can provide much help here as I struggle just as much with it! Perhaps, the following example helps a bit: instead of a Cauchy process, we simply the situation by considering a pure jump Lévy process $X$ of finite variation, i.e. a Lévy process with characteristics $(0,0,\nu)$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} x\; d\nu(x) < +\infty$ (which is much stronger than the usual assumption. In this context, if we write $\Delta X_t := X_t - X_{t-}$ for the jumps, then we can write $X = X_0 + \sum_{s \leq t} \Delta_s$.

Comment: This sum can only make sense if the number of jumps is countable! (And even then, we must make sure that it converges, which is only the case because the process has finite variation!!) If there were an uncountable number of jumps, we couldn't even make sense of this sum.
This does not entirely answer your question, but perhaps it gives you a bit more intuition...

Comment: In the general context, you have to think about jumps in the following way: there is a jump at $t$ iff $\Delta X_t = X_t - X_{t-}\neq 0$. Note that this object exists, because $X$ is càdlàg! Then, saying that there the jump times are exactly $\mathbb{Q}$ means exactly that the function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. This might sound very weird, but this is very similar to the behaviour of the function discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960887/show-that-the-function-f-is-continuous-only-at-the-irrational-points.